# Save memory of queries

Tags: mysql, mongodb, memory, neo4j, resultset

i have a program in Java that execute queries on mysql, mongodb and neo4j.
I want to store the memory used by my java program in each instant during the query and store into an array.

> Here's and example of a query in mysql

```
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        String sql = "SELECT IDUSER, NAME, CITY FROM EMPLOYEES";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several programs that uses memory for your work.

The first one is your java program, as you use a **SELECT** in your code and the data will transmitted from DB to your program space, it totally depend to the size of `ResultSet`. Other objects has the same size.

Another program is your DBMS which uses memory to load data from disk and send it back to your Java program. In DBMS also it depend to the size of requested data.

However if you want the total memory used in system, you can use some useful OS commands, like `free` or `top` in linux.